# Extract a dictionary objects to a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i need a small help to put the content returned from dictionary to 2 different list.

The code is :

```
for region in regions:
    instance_information = {}
    ip_dict = {}
    client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
    addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses().get('Addresses')

    for address in addresses_dict:
        if address.get('InstanceId'):
            instance_information[address['InstanceId']] = [address.get('PublicIp')]

    dex_dict = client.describe_tags().get('Tags')
    for dex in dex_dict:
        if instance_information.get(dex['ResourceId']):
            instance_information[dex['ResourceId']].append(dex.get('Value'))
    print (json.dumps(instance_information,indent=4))
```

This returns :

```
{
    "i-c581ea32": [
        "52.113.42.171", 
        "SDL Exclusive LB", 
        "pdx01-ms-pdl-lb01"
    ], 
    "i-b8601217": [
        "52.26.21.83", 
        "pdx-LBi-b8609671", 
        "HAProxy Server", 
        "us-west-2", 
        "pdx02-cloud-trial01", 
        "subnet-d86be1af", 
        "us-west-2b"
    ], 
    "i-3c2b02ca": [
        "52.13.84.44", 
        "pdx01-lb02"
    ], 
    "i-986fc140": [
        "52.3.173.116", 
        "pdx-hprod-LBi-316fc340", 
        "HAProxy Server", 
        "us-west-2", 
        "pdx02-he-prod", 
        "subnet-bcdcd6cb", 
        "us-west-2b"
    ], 
    "i-035a2c4": [
        "5.33.81.148", 
        "pdx-ece-prod-LBi-022c4", 
        "HAProxy Server", 
        "us-west-2", 
        "pdx02-emsce-prod
```

I just need to extract the IP and put it in a dict . I need to pass this IP to another `def` , How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension is your tool:

```
iplist = [v[0] for v in instance_information.values()]
```

EDIT:
As you need, make a function that returns you the ips

```
def getIpFromRegions(regions):
  for region in regions:
      instance_information = {}
      ip_dict = {}
      client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
      addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses().get('Addresses')

      for address in addresses_dict:
          if address.get('InstanceId'):
              instance_information[address['InstanceId']] = [address.get('PublicIp')]

      dex_dict = client.describe_tags().get('Tags')
      for dex in dex_dict:
          if instance_information.get(dex['ResourceId']):
              instance_information[dex['ResourceId']].append(dex.get('Value'))
      yield [v[0] for v in instance_information.values()]
```

EDIT2:

For all combined ip of region make a comprehension over your new function:

```
allip = [ip for ip in ips for ips in getIpFromRegions(regions)]
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how do i place this in my code?

Comment: check the edit: this will yield the ip list for each region,

Comment: Okay , nicely done i have another question probably will paste soon

Comment: Danian , can you tell me how can the result can be shown in combined form , because this is showing me in 3 dicts for 3 regions being passed

Answer (score 1):

You may simple iterate over all the values in the given dictionary and select the first element as the IP to append it in a new list.

```
ip_list = [i[0]for i in instance_information.values()]
>> ['52.113.42.171', '52.26.21.83', '52.13.84.44', '5.33.81.148', '52.3.173.116']
```

Or if you need a dictionary like structure then you may try:

```
instance_information_ip = {i:instance_information[i][0] for i in instance_information}
>>> {'i-c581ea32': '52.113.42.171', 'i-b8601217': '52.26.21.83', 'i-3c2b02ca': '52.13.84.44', 'i-986fc140': '52.3.173.116', 'i-035a2c4': '5.33.81.148'}
```

Comment: Where do i place this ? can u elaborate

Comment: Replace the `print (json.dumps(instance_information,indent=4))` with any of the above snippet.

Comment: okay cool, and if i want to fetch any other elment say the 2nd one i chance i[0] to i[1] ?